# Degrees of freedom in a Multivariate t Distribution?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Can I have different degrees of freedom for each dimension in a Multivariate t Distribution? The functions that I use in Matlab (mvtpdf) and Mathematica (MultivariateTDistribution) accept only one parameter of degrees of freedom. What I want is to have different degrees of freedom for each dimension. I think this will represent my data more efficiently. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question as being, can I construct a multivariate distribution that has student-T distributions with different degrees of freedom as its marginals.

You can do it with [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29).  You could use `CopulaDistribution` [see [ref-page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CopulaDistribution.html)] in *Mathematica* 8 to construct a multivariate distribution with arbitrary set of marginals. The choice of copula kernel depends on details of what you are trying to achieve.